# Transitions an arrow-, bullet-, thumbnail- and key-navigation

Tags: jssor

It has already been suggested several times that the a.m. navigations also use the transitions used in "autoplay".

I would like to support that, because the current handling of just moving the slides sort of breaks the "look and feel" of the slider behaviour.

"Swiping" and "dragging" could stay as is.

Maybe configurable with an option???

Have tried to solve that myself in the code, but failed miserably so far :-( :-).

Comment: Jssor Slideshow transition must play with 2 slides. The mechanism is to transform old slide out and new slide in. Given a slideshow is playing and request navigation at meantime, it will crash the logic. As a matter of fact, it has really been suggested for many time. I will consider this feature in the next version named 'Jssor Slideo'.